Update step of Bayes filter using Bayes rule
In Probabilistic Machine Learning: Advanced Topics, when discussing the update step of the Bayes filter (equation 8.5) the following is presented,

The update step is just the Bayes' rule:
$p(\boldsymbol{z_t}|\boldsymbol{y}_{1:t}) = \frac{1}{Z_t}p(\boldsymbol{y}_t|\boldsymbol{z}_t)p(\boldsymbol{z}_t|\boldsymbol{y}_{1:t-1})$

where $\boldsymbol{z}_t$ are the latent states (to be estimated) and $\boldsymbol{y}_{1:t-1}$ are the observations.
However, I don't follow how we can arrive at the right hand side using Bayes rule. I can write
$p(\boldsymbol{z_t}|\boldsymbol{y}_{1:t}) = \frac{1}{Z_t}p(\boldsymbol{z}_t)p(\boldsymbol{y}_{1:t}|\boldsymbol{z_t})$
but then I'm stuck.
